# Flex 3 - Font in textArea is different between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, flex3

I have a problem with Flex. I'm using a mx:textArea with fontFamily "Courier New".

If i use Chrome, in a row there are for example 23 chars, instead with Firefox there are 25. Same font and same font-size.

How can i resolve it?

Comment: have you tried a reset on letter-spacing ? is font been drawn as smooth/thick on both browsers ?

Comment: I has set the property  letterSpacing="0" in the textArea. But it was not worked.